# Change the audio file format depending on the browser?

Tags: html, html5-audio, browser-detection

I made an image and when a user clicks certain field on that image he is able to hear sound, the problem is that the file format is mp3, so all browsers except opera plays that sound fine, how can I fix that ?
Looks like this:

```
<audio loop id="e" src="e.mp3" preload="auto"></audio>    
<div class="string" id="ee" -->   onclick="document.getElementById('ee').play();
  document.getElementById('a').pause(); document.getElementById('a').currentTime = 0;
  document.getElementById('d').pause(); document.getElementById('d').currentTime = 0;
  document.getElementById('g').pause(); document.getElementById('g').currentTime = 0; 
  document.getElementById('b').pause(); document.getElementById('b').currentTime = 0; 
  document.getElementById('e').pause(); document.getElementById('e').currentTime = 0;">
</div>
```

Comment: Are you using the `codecs` parameter in the `source` tag? Please post your code.

Comment: `if(navigator.appName == "Opera") { elem.src="newSRC.wav"; }`

Comment: @SquareCat no, simply <audio> tag

Comment: @ZachSaucier is there a way to do a similar thing in HTML5? I don't want to rewrite all of my stuff to javascript for that -_-

Comment: Have you tried adding an appropriate `type` attribute?

Comment: You wouldn't have to rewrite it all, just add that one line into a javascript section. If it's not Opera it will default to whatever you have

Comment: @ZachSaucier thx, didn't think about that, maybe I need a little sleep :)

Comment: If you wanted you could put the script into a [`onloadeddata`](http://stackoverflow.com/a/8059487/2065702) attribute, thus avoiding a separate section (I doubt you're worried about the performance of loading an extra mp3 file, that's another issue if so)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want use audio element on website you must use 2 type format audio mp3 and ogg
[read about that](http://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_audio.asp)

if you have only mp3 you can use this [audio5js](http://zohararad.github.io/audio5js/)

Comment: this is what I've been looking for