# How can we force html to play 100% buffer audio or video?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, audio, video

I really need to buffer entire audio/video before playing it. On normal case browser will buffer only some portion of audio/video. How to force browser to buffer 100% video before playing it?Or how to trigger buffer after playing it once.

Comment: directly, you cannot. you can however mute and pragmatically advance the playhead, pausing just after an advance, thus triggering the buffering.

Comment: how to trigger complete buffer after playing it?

Comment: thanks your comment helped me

Answer (score 0):

Maybe in jQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
var audioElement = document.createElement('audio');
    audioElement.setAttribute('src', 'audio_file.mp3');
    audioElement.play();
```

});

or like this:
[How do you check if a HTML5 audio element is loaded?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8059434/how-do-you-check-if-a-html5-audio-element-is-loaded)