# How to change iframe sources by order?

Tags: javascript, html

I want to change this code from changing the sources of iframe randomly to be by order

```
<script type="text/javascript">

function newSite() {
    var sites = ['Experiment1/index.html',
                 'Experiment2/index.html',
                 'Experiment3/index.html']

    document.getElementById('myIframe').src = sites[Math.floor(Math.random() * sites.length)];
}    
</script>
```

when clicking on this button and also this is the iframe

```
<iframe id="myIframe" src="Experiment1/index.html" allowfullscreen="true"  scrolling="no"></iframe><br/>
<input type="button" value="Go to next level" onClick="newSite()" />
```

Comment: did you try your code? Can you provide a jsfiddle? Looks ok to me.

Comment: I know that it is okay but what I am trying to do t make the srcs change in order not randomly like what it is shown above

Comment: @shrouk, what do you mean in order? Why can't you just replace the Math.random() part with a number?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try defining `sites` array outside of function, using `.shift()`

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var sites = ['Experiment1/index.html',
            'Experiment2/index.html',
            'Experiment3/index.html'];

function newSite() {

    var curr = sites.shift();
    sites[sites.length] = curr;
    document.getElementById('myIframe').src = curr;
}    
</script>
<iframe id="myIframe"
        src="Experiment1/index.html"
        allowfullscreen="true" 
        scrolling="no"></iframe><br/>
<input type="button" value="Go to next level" onClick="newSite()" />
```

plnkr http://plnkr.co/edit/cQZznvyltX46UO1Y0lDG?p=preview

Comment: @shrouk Can you describe "It didn't work"? Commented out `<iframe>` element; results should be displayed at `console` at stacksnippets. Will create a plnkr http://plnkr.co

Comment: Now the iframe doesn't go to another src when clicking go to next level button

Comment: what @guest271314 gave you work. You just have to uncomment the document.getElementById to set the new src

Comment: Now it worked the error was that there wasn't a ; after sites[sites.length] = curr 
Thanks

Comment: Thanks alot for your help now I have one problem that the Experiment1/index.html src opens 2 times as it is in the src of the iframe and also in the array in the script function

Comment: @shrouk  _"now I have one problem that the Experiment1/index.html src opens 2 times as it is in the src of the iframe and also in the array in the script function"_ You can adjust `sites` array to `var sites = ['Experiment2/index.html',
            'Experiment3/index.html',
            'Experiment1/index.html'];`

Comment: Thanks alot guys :D

Comment: Done 
I am sorry I was working on the rest of the code :)

Comment: How can I put a video before opening these sources and when it ends the first src opens?

Comment: @shrouk Are you trying to create a media playlist?

Comment: No its a game with levels so its an intro video

Comment: @shrouk You should write the Question, include all relevant details; the portions you are having issues with; `html`, `css`, `js`; describe expected result

Comment: I just need a js code that moves the iframe when the video ends to those srcs

Comment: You can use the `onended` event of `video` element. See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/Events/Media_events , http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36380408/does-the-preload-attribute-of-audio-affect-the-window-onload-event-time ,

Comment: This is the code I am using 
<script type="text/javascript">
  $("#myVideo").on("ended", function() {
      window.location.href='Experiment1/index.html';   
      });
    </script>
but for some reason it doesn't work

Comment: Are you trying to change the `src` of the `iframe`? Why are you using `window.location.href`?