# How to check if the recieved audio src url is working or not?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, asynchronous, promise, fetch

I have to play song as per user input . My backend is in python which fetches from some api and provides the song source to play to the frontend (reactjs). Some of the links are broken and cannot play. So I need to identify which are broken so that it wud not cause bad UX.

I have tried these workarounds-

- `fetch` request to the obtained link and if it returns `status` other than `200` 
  This did not work and provided `CORS Not Allowed` warning in console and also the request just passed to `catch` and I was unable to check status in `then`.
- using `play() promise`

  ```
  var context = new AudioContext();
  var source = context.createBufferSource();
  var audioFile = new Audio();
  audioFile.src= audio['audiosrc'];
  var playPromise = audioFile.play()
  console.log(playPromise);
  playPromise.then(() => {console.log('ok')})
  .catch((err) => {console.log('err')
  console.log(err);
  fetch('https://app.boorish86.hasura-app.io/stream', {
    method: 'POST',
    body: JSON.stringify({
      src: audio['audiosrc']
    }),
    headers: {
      "Content-type": "application/json; charset=UTF-8"
    }
  })
  .then(response => response.arrayBuffer())
  .then(response => {console.log(response)    
      context.decodeAudioData(response, function(decodedData) {
      source.buffer = decodedData;
      source.connect(context.destination);
      source.start(0) });
  })
  .catch(err => console.log(err))
  })
  ```

None of these workarounds help me since I have to pass `src` to some other react custom play component.Nd this is not happenning on pasing source downt to a child component.

Also checking from `oncanplaythrough, canplay , onloadeddata` is not working for me . It gives same output for broken as well as non broken links

Comment: Try playing audio with 0 volume and test. If successful then do necessary ui.

Comment: @bennygenel how do I find out if the audio played or not at volume 0?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do you check if a HTML5 audio element is loaded?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8059434/how-do-you-check-if-a-html5-audio-element-is-loaded)

Comment: @Roamer-1888 i tried it .. it doesn't work for me...